# Scala import class error

Tags: class, scala, import

Having a problem with Scala import. I have an import problem with two classes. The first one:

```
package org.world
import org.gui.tokens.Token


object WorldObject {

}

abstract class WorldObject[A <: WorldObject[_]](var xPos: Float, var yPos: Float) {
  def x = xPos
  def y = yPos

  def token: Token
             ^^^^^
  def move(dx: Float, dy: Float) {// : A = new A(x + dx, y + dy)
    xPos += dx // = x + dx
    yPos += dy
  }
}
```

and the second one:

```
package org.gui.tokens

object Token {

}
```

And the problem is that the return type of `def token: Token` is underlined in red with error saying

> not found: type Token

All is fine with class locations. Other classes have no similar problems. I do not remember such a situation in Java, autoimport always worked perfectly. Here it only adds the `import org.gui.tokens.Token` statement repeatedly in the `WorldObject` file over and over again... why is that? What can I do about it?

Comment: Now when I understand the problem, I believe that the autoimport in Scala IDE must somehow react on this and not just silently import the object instead of a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Token` is an object, so saying `def token: Token` makes about as much sense to the compiler as saying `def token: 5` or `def token: "Hello"`.

You either mean `def token = Token`, if you want to return the `Token` object; or you mean `class Token {}; object Token extends Token {}` in your tokens file, so there really is a class named `Token`, or you mean `def token: Token.type`, which means that the method must return something of the type of the *object* `Token`.  (But there's not much point, since the object `Token` is the only thing with the type `Token.type`.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, 'underlined in red' implies that you are asking about a particular IDE for Scala (Eclipse, IDEA?).

`object Token` is a singleton object, there is no general type `Token` which could be instantiated! There is exactly one object, so `def token: Token` wrongly suggests that there could be different tokens. You can rectify this in two ways. First by using the singleton type of `Token`:

```
def token: Token.type
```

or, since there is only one way to return such an object, you can already provide the implementation:

```
def token: Token.type = Token
```

or short

```
def token = Token
```

However, the usefulness of this is questionable. Anyone looking for object `Token` can directly talk to it, instead of the method indirection.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is Eclipse... And thanks to your answer I understand that my mistake is that I did not create a class `Token`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with packages, but instead with Objects.

You marked Token as an object instead of as a class. This would be similar to marking every method in a Java class to static, but in Scala, there is not chance of declaration.

```
    package org.gui.tokens
    class Token {
    }
```

Remember, because Objects have just one instance and cannot be extended, they cannot be used as identifiers.